# options caption and subscribe in dropdown knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I Have a dropdown which has some status for e.g like Delivered, Cancelled, Failure, Inprogress. I am using drop down to bind the values using knockout. Below is the sample code.

```
<select id="ddlStatus" data-bind="options: status, optionsText: 'statusName', optionsValue:  'statusId', optionsCaption: '', value : $root.SelectedStatus"></select>
```

I want the optionsCaption to be defaulted to the first option of "status" collection. Basically instead of a hardcoded caption in the dropdown i want the first option in the status to be default option. I am using subscribe for "selected status" and it called every time if i dont give the Optionscaptions.

Comment: `SelectedStatus` is `undefined` initially. If you don't have an `optionsCaption`, the first option is *set* as its value. So, `subscribe` obviously gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The default behavior

When knockout renders the options in your view, it tries to immediately sync the right selection:

```js
ko.applyBindings({ options: [1, 2, 3], selection: ko.observable(2) })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: options, value: selection"></select>
```

### The cause of your problem

If you don't have a predefined selection, knockout will default to the *first* item in the options list (just like an ordinary static HTML `<select>` element would.)

Since the `value` binding binds two-ways, knockout will *actually **set** `selected`* upon calling `applyBindings`.

Any subscriptions to `selection` will be triggered:

```js
var vm = { options: [1, 2, 3], selection: ko.observable() };
vm.selection.subscribe(console.log.bind(console, "CHANGED:"));

ko.applyBindings(vm)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: options, value: selection"></select>
```

### The solution

If you don't want this subscription to happpen, the easiest solution is to *predefine the `selection` with the default value: the first item in options*:

Any subscriptions to `selection` will be triggered:

```js
var vm = { options: [1, 2, 3], selection: ko.observable() };

// Make sure there's a defined selection that is in our options:
vm.selection(vm.options[0])

vm.selection.subscribe(console.log.bind(console, "CHANGED:"));

ko.applyBindings(vm)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: options, value: selection"></select>
```

Comment: please note that this drop down is in a grid and we are displaying the drop down for each row. even though i have set the selection for each drop down also then also the subscribe code is got called multiple times

Comment: The subscribe code can be triggered from other parts of your app as well. If there's an initial selection, and the selected item appears in your options array, `applyBindings` will not trigger a change. Can you share some code that illustrates the problem you're still having?